# Restrict SSO to specific users

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforce-id, single-sign-on, delegated-authentication, adfs

I've implemented SSO with Salesforce using ADFS. Currently all users can login to Salesforce via SSO. I'd like to limit SSO to a subset of users based on user groups defined in AD. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: In addition to the referenced Q&A above, a simple solution is outlined [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204540/service-accounts-with-salesforce-and-okta-saml-for-everything-else)

Comment: Well i understand that i can leverage that feature by enabling Delegated Authentication in sales force, but i already have Employees in AD groups so my question would be can i leverage say Accounting (Ad Group) to have SSO enabled and anyone not apart of that group not have SSO ?

Comment: You can map and sync AD groups to Salesforce via [Identity Connect](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=identityconnect_about.htm&type=5). The groups could become Profiles and/or PermissionSets in Salesforce. The answers above show you how you can take Profile and/or PermissionSet and include or exclude it from SSO.